# Problems when embed an UIStackView in an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uistackview

I'm setting up an iOS app interface from the Interface Builder.
I've several horizontal stack views, all embedded in a single vertical stackview. Up to here, the layout seems to be ok and the constraints are well done.

When I embed the vertical stack view in a UIScrollView, the layout turns very bad. There's probably something wrong with my layout constraints, but I do not really know what. Here are two images that represent the layout before and after the embed in the UIScrollView:

[image: Before UIScrollView]

[image: After UIScrollView]

Does anyone have an idea of ​​why this happens?
Thanks in advance guys.

**Update**

After installing this constraint:

```
VerticalStackView.width == ScrollView.width
```

The result is the following:

[image: VerticalStackView.width == ScrollView.width img]

**Update 2**

[image: After the addition of the basic constraints]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the following view hierarchy (screenshot) and constraints and you should be good to go:

- `ScrollView.top == View.top`
- `ScrollView.leading == View.leading`
- `ScrollView.bottom == View.bottom`
- `ScrollView.trailing == View.trailing`
- `ContentView.top == ScrollView.top`
- `ContentView.leading == ScrollView.leading`
- `ContentView.bottom == ScrollView.bottom`
- `ContentView.trailing == ScrollView.trailing`
- `ContentView.width == ScrollView.width`
- `VerticalStackView.top == ContentView.top + 16`
- `VerticalStackView.leading == ContentView.leading + 16`
- `VerticalStackView.bottom == ContentView.bottom - 16`
- `VerticalStackView.trailing == ContentView.trailing - 16`

Instead of the `View` within the first four constraints you can also use the `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` (depending on your needs).

[image: setup]

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. See the result in my question's update.

Comment: I thought you had already set up basic constraints. Updated my answer with all the constraints that are needed.

Comment: This is the right way, but i can't set trailing + 16 margin from the UIScrollView. See my update

Comment: You can use an additional content view (regular `UIView`) as the scrollview's subview and put your vertical stackview within that content view with the margins you like. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I try. Would you be able to explain to me why anyway there are these problems on the constraints?

Comment: Done! Thank you! Maybe the problem is that i've setted OuterStackView.width == ScrollView.width

Comment: When you set your vertical stackview's width to be equal to the scrollview's width (which is the device's width) everything is fine (e.g. 320 == 320). but setting equal widths and also a leading and trailing margin of 16 results in "conflicting constraints" because the views' widths can't be equal when there is a margin around the stackview. to fix this you could set the stackview's width to be equal to the scrollview's width - 32.